# Scraping leaderboard table on golf website in R

Tags: r, selenium, rvest, xml2

The PGA tour's website has a [leaderboard page](https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html) page and I am trying to scrape the main table on the website for a project.

```
library(dplyr)
leaderboard_table <- xml2::read_html('https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html') %>% 
  html_nodes('table') %>% 
  html_table()
```

however instead of pulling the tables, it returns this odd output...
[image]

Other pages such as the [schedule page](https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/schedule.html) scrape fine without any issues, see below. It is only the leaderboard page I am having trouble with.

```
schedule_url <- 'https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/schedule.html'
schedule_table <- xml2::read_html(schedule_url) %>% html_nodes('table.table-styled') %>% html_table()
schedule_df <- schedule_table[[1]]
# this works fine
```

**Edit Before Bounty:** the below answer is a helpful start, however there is a problem. The JSON files name changes based on the round (`/r/003` for 3rd round) and probably based on other aspects of the golf tournament as well. Currently there is this that i see in the elements tab:

[image]

...however, using the leaderboard url link to the `.json` file `https://lbdata.pgatour.com/2021/r/005/leaderboard.json` is not helping... instead, I receive this error when using `jsonlite::fromJson`

[image]

Two questions then:

1. Is is possible to read this .JSON file into R? (perhaps it is protected in some way)? Maybe just an issue on my end, or am I missing something else in R here?
2. Given that the URL changes, how can I dynamically grab the URL value in R? It would be great if I could grab all of the `global.leaderboardConfig` object somehow, because that would give me access to the `leaderboardUrl`.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, this page is dynamically generated by some `javascript`.
Even the `json` file address seems to be dynamic, and the address you're trying to open isn't valid anymore :

```
https://lbdata.pgatour.com/2021/r/003/leaderboard.json?userTrackingId=exp=1612495792~acl=*~hmac=722f704283f795e8121198427386ee075ce41e93d90f8979fd772b223ea11ab9

An error occurred while processing your request.

Reference #199.cf05d517.1613439313.4ed8cf21
```

To get the data, you could use [RSelenium](https://docs.ropensci.org/RSelenium/articles/basics.html) after installing a [Docker Selenium server](https://docs.ropensci.org/RSelenium/articles/docker.html).
The installation is straight forward, and `Docker` is designed to make images work out of the box.

After `Docker` installation, running the `Selenium` server is as simple as:

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0
```

Note that this as a whole requires over `2 Gb` disk space.

`Selenium` emulates a Web browser and allows among others to get the final `HTML` content of the page, after rendering of the `javascript`:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4445L,
  browserName = "firefox"
)
# Open connexion to Selenium server
remDr$open()
remDr$getStatus()

remDr$navigate("https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html")

players <- xml2::read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>% 
                 html_nodes(".player-name-col")   %>% 
                 html_text()

total <- xml2::read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>% 
               html_nodes(".total") %>%
               html_text()

data.frame(players = players, total = total[-1])

                     players total
1        Daniel Berger  (PB)   -18
2     Maverick McNealy  (PB)   -16
3      Patrick Cantlay  (PB)   -15
4        Jordan Spieth  (PB)   -15
5           Paul Casey  (PB)   -14
6         Nate Lashley  (PB)   -14
7      Charley Hoffman  (PB)   -13
8     Cameron Tringale  (PB)   -13
...
```

As the table doesn't use the `table` tag, `html_table` doesn't work and columns need to be extracted individually.

Comment: This is great. An `rvest` solution would be great but it makes sense why `RSelenium` may be better for this, for the reasons you stated.

Comment: Accepted this answer because I'm not sure a better one exists / is coming. Thanks @Waldi

Answer (score 4):

This page uses javascript to render the page and the data you seek is stored as a JSON file.  Using the developer tools from your browser and looking on the Network tab you should be able to find the link to the "leaderboard.json" file.

You can access this file directly:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON("https://lbdata.pgatour.com/2021/r/003/leaderboard.json?userTrackingId=exp=1612495792~acl=*~hmac=722f704283f795e8121198427386ee075ce41e93d90f8979fd772b223ea11ab9")
```

It is a pretty complicated list but you should be able to navigate through the different elements to find the desired information.

Comment: When you check the html code, what do see to control if the table is linked to the json file?

Comment: @EarlMascetti, The file is referenced is listed under one of the script tags.  I unusual bypass this and go directly to the Network tab and look at the JSON files first before trying to reverse engineer the html.

Comment: this is great i'll give this a try soon and come back w/ updates

Comment: see the edit in my post for updates finally.