# Scraping html header with R

Tags: html, r, xml, rvest

#### My objective

I'm attempting to use R to scrape text from a web page: https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/stationhome.html?id=8467150. For the purposes of this question, my goal is to access the header text that contains the station number ("Bridgeport, CT - Station ID: 8467150"). Below is a screenshot of the page. I've highlighted the text that I'm trying to verify is present, and the text is also highlighted in the inspect element pane.

[image: A screenshot of the target web page. The text I am looking for is highlighted in yellow, and selected in the element inspection pane]

My old approach was to access the full text of the site with `readLines()`. A recent update to the website has made the text more difficult to access, and the station name/number is no longer visible to `readLines()`:

```
url <- "https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/stationhome.html?id=8467150"
stn <- "8467150"

webpage <- readLines(url, warn = FALSE)

### grep indicates that the station number is not present in the scraped text
grep(x = webpage, pattern = stn, value = TRUE)
```

#### Potential solutions

I am therefore looking for a new way to access my target text. I have tried using httr, but still cannot get all the html text to be included in what I scrape from the web page. The XML and rvest packages also seem promising, but I am not sure how to identify the relevant CSS selector or XPath expression.

```
### an attempt using httr
hDat <- httr::RETRY("GET", url, times = 10)
txt  <- httr::content(hDat, "text")

### grep indicates that the station number is still not present
grep(x = txt, pattern = stn, value = TRUE)


### a partial attempt using XML
h  <- xml2::read_html(url)
h2 <- XML::htmlTreeParse(h, useInternalNodes=TRUE, asText = TRUE)

### this may end up working, but I'm not sure how to identify the correct path
html.parse <- XML::xpathApply(h2, path = "div.span8", XML::xmlValue)
```

Regardless of the approach, I would welcome any suggestions that can help me access the header text containing the station name/number.

Comment: While you're looking at the debugging page of your browser, go to the *Network* tab and reload the page, sort by *Type*, click on the first "json" entry, then look at the Response for that query. It's possible that the raw data you need is already encapsulated in JSON, with no dynamic-page web-scraping required.

Comment: If you don't find the associated JSON, you could use `RSelenium`, as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66217591/13513328)

Comment: The page is dynamically produced you will have better luck trying the "rnoaa" package or accessing the API directly.  See https://api.tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/prod/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use Selenium, it will be very hard.
NOAA encourages you to access their free Restful json APIs. It also goes to great lengths to discourage html scraping.

That said, the following code will get what you want from a NOAA json in a data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

j1 <- fromJSON(txt = 'https://api.tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/mdapi/prod/webapi/stations/8467150.json', simplifyDataFrame = TRUE, flatten = TRUE)

j1$stations %>% as_tibble() %>% select(name, state, id)
```

## Results

```
    # A tibble: 1 x 3
  name       state id     
  <chr>      <chr> <chr>  
1 Bridgeport CT    8467150
```