# In R, use rvest and xml2 to extract JSON object from a <script> element on website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

Previously posted a [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66056386/scraping-leaderboard-table-on-golf-website-in-r/66217591) about scraping a table on the leaderboard page of the PGA's website [on this page](https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html). To summarize that post, the leaderboard table is difficult to scrape apparently because of the way this page uses javascript to render the page and table.

I can inspect and I see in the  tag that there is an object `global.leaderboardConfig` with useful info:

[image]

Is it possible to get this object as a list in R? I am able to grab all 76 script elements on the page using `xml2::read_html('https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html') %>% html_nodes('script')`, however I'm not sure how to identify the specific script tag needed, nor how to get an object out of it.

**Edit:** In the networks tab of devtools, there is also this request which provides the link for an API call that gets the data. Rather than fetching the object from the script tag, perhaps it is easier to grab all network requests and sift through those instead?

[image]

Comment: You could just use `grep()` to fill the script with  "leaderboard.json" in it.  The tricky part is figuring out the key to generate the correct hmac hash value.  That is the "*~hmac=" part of the html request need to retrieve the file.

Comment: yes it looks like hmac value changes - this is why i am interested in finding a way to grab these values in R

Comment: If this is the link "https://lbdata.pgatour.com/2021/r/012/leaderboard.json?userTrackingId=exp=1618615376~acl=*~hmac=d232b593715c434061bbea0a52d75760d706487cf00ebea3672dbf4c178fd520".  "exp=1618615376" is just the expiration time of the link, in seconds from 1/1/1970.  hmac=..., is the has value which is calculated to make the request.  This is most likely a SHA-256 hash value, the problem is determining where or how the key value is calculated to perform the hash.

Comment: Yes that is the link. However even the front part of the link `lbdata.pgatour.com/2021/r/012/` changes form time to time. Rather than re-creating the hash value, it seems easier (if possible) to simply grab all network requests made by the page. Then I can simply search them for `lbdata.pgatour.com` for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This site generates the `hmac` and `expire` url parameters value from a JS function that is using a specific algorithm. The arguments of this algorithm are depending on the epoch time which is passed as url parameter to the JS file hosting that function [here](https://microservice.pgatour.com/js?_=1618868625306). This way, the `hmac` value is different each time because it's processed from this file whose url is changing constantly.

This algorithm consists of bitwise and & xor like this (pseudocode):

```
step = ((value * value - fixedValue) & bitMask) ^ xorKey1
result += fromCharCode(step)
value = step

step = ((value * value - fixedValue) & bitMask) ^ xorKey2
result += fromCharCode(step)
value = step

....
....
```

The `xorKey` numbers are generated dynamically on `https://microservice.pgatour.com/js` based on epoch time. You just need to request this js file with the current epoch time as url parameter and extract with regex all `stepValues` that are required in the above algorithm (starting with `-1`). You will also need to reproduce the alogithm above in [r](/questions/tagged/r)

The following script generates the url parameters and makes the API call:

```
library(httr)
library(stringr)
library(bitops)

# fixed values
init <- 4294967295
value <- 101
encodedId <- 1798339286
result <- rawToChar(as.raw(value))

# epoch time is dynamic
time <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))*1000

output <- content(GET("https://microservice.pgatour.com/js", query = list(
    "_" = format(time, digits=13)
  )), as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")

steps <- regmatches(output, gregexpr("-1[0-9]+", output, perl=TRUE)) #extract steps
stepsNum <- as.numeric(unlist(steps)) #convert to num

for(t in stepsNum){
    step <- bitXor(bitAnd(value * value - encodedId, init), t)
    result <- paste0(result, rawToChar(as.raw(step)));
    value <- step;
}
print(result)

# extract leaderboard config url
output <- content(GET("https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html"), as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
configUrl = gsub("\\\\/", "/", str_match(output, "\\leaderboardUrl:\\s*'(.*)'")[2])

url = paste0(configUrl,"?userTrackingId=",result)
data <- content(GET(url), as = "parsed", type = "application/json")

print(data)
```

kaggle link: https://www.kaggle.com/bertrandmartel/pgatourextract

### How to find this algorithm ?

I've searched in the Javascript code and reversed the obfuscated code to be decoded into something understandable. This is quite a long way to go. Let's go there step by step.

#### Mission n°1 - search for `leaderboardUrl`

You've given the first hint in your question, the location of the `config` where there is a `leaderboardUrl`.

There is [this JS file](https://lbdata.pgatour.com/react-lb-js/298fab0/stroke-play-leaderboard-controller-56223356ffc8423f5d6e.js) named `stroke-play-leaderboard-controller-56223356ffc8423f5d6e.js` that have occurences of `leaderboardUrl` in `config.leaderboardUrl`:

```js
{
    key: "getLeaderboardData",
    value: function (t, r, n) {
      var o = this,
        e = (0, h.resolveUrl)(this.config.leaderboardUrl, r()),  <===================== HERE
        a = [this.performFetch(e)].concat(
          g(
            "initial" === n && this.config.translationsUrl
              ? [y.default.load(this.config.translationsUrl)]
              : []
          )
        ),
        ..........
}
```

Let's look at `performFetch` function that seems to send the request

```js
{
    key: "performFetch",
    value: function (t) {
      var r = this,
        e =
          1 < arguments.length && void 0 !== arguments[1]
            ? arguments[1]
            : {};
      return t
        ? ((0, a.isProtectedUrl)(t) &&
            (t = this.getUrlWithAuth(t)), <===================== HERE
          (0, o.default)(t, e)
            .then(function (e) {
              return r.checkFetchResponseStatus(e, t);
    .................
```

We've spotted the `getUrlWithAuth` function:

```js
  {
    key: "getUrlWithAuth",
    value: function (e) {
      var t = u.setTrackingUserId, 
        r = u.UserIdTracker, 
        n = r && r.getTrackingUserIdParam && r.getUserId; <===================== HERE
      if (t && n) {
        var o = r.getTrackingUserIdParam(), <===================== HERE
          a = t(r.getUserId());
        return u.setUrlParameter(e, o, a);
      }
      return e;
    },
  },
```

Now, we have `getUserId` and `getTrackingUserIdParam` that look like the function and variable adding the authorization parameters to the url. The problem is we have to find where is this function located.

#### Mission n°2 - Deobfuscation challenge: substitutions

I've spotted [this file](https://www.pgatour.com/etc/designs/pgatour-libs/frontend/pgatour/main.c03ddfd249437fcce43410c35a21c6f8.js) named `main.c03ddfd249437fcce43410c35a21c6f8.js` where there is an occurence of `getUserId` and `getTrackingUserIdParam` :

```js
var t = ["PCl", "tUp", "set", "270981fHMpFv", "13687NsSiEo", "rId", "cri", "onR", "DEV", "oTr", "Int", "Tra", "_PR", "val", "1ceOiGP", "sts", "oad", "Fin", "_UA", "ing", "IdP", "TA_", "Scr", "erI", "hTo", "use", "erv", "tim", "tus", "205913gYUZtZ", "ara", "Use", "sta", "STA", "LBD", "pat", "253565HlVREe", "rva", "Ref", "now", "ien", "ref", "89874aJWuvR", "scr", "HTT", "arI", "equ", "efo", "Eve", "ngU", "1eAGUfS", "Url", "bef", "onl", "res", "p:/", "add", "nte", "rlT", "IdS", "Loa", "157231BKOPfc", "1YJedti", "hIn", "ate", "ser", "TDA", "bin", "upd", "xEr", "tou", "dHo", "ps:", "din", "931", "isU", "aja", "tup", "ste", "ntL", "Pat", "_DE", "ays", "onO", "edA", "Sen", "261593SNtpWc", "ore", "gth", "las", "730", "ame", "ter", "ime", "UAT", "id8", "ues", "est", "rtT", "xSe", "ist", "ptL", "ATA", "len", "ipt", "get", "pga", "Tru", "rep", "ish", "url", "alw", "dat", "ack", "lac", "onB", "uld", "cki", "ken", "ind", "onS", "sho", "htt", "ror", "API"];
var A = function(g, e) {
    return t[g -= 398]
},
(function(g, e) {
    for (var t = A; ; )
        try {
            if (189298 === parseInt(t(494)) + -parseInt(t(508)) * parseInt(t(461)) + -parseInt(t(519)) + parseInt(t(419)) + -parseInt(t(520)) * -parseInt(t(487)) + parseInt(t(472)) * -parseInt(t(462)) + -parseInt(t(500)))
                break;
            g.push(g.shift())
        } catch (e) {
            g.push(g.shift())
        }
}
)(t)
.................
function(g, e) {
    var t = A
      , C = e[t(439) + t(403) + "r"] = e["pga" + t(403) + "r"] || {}
      , I = t(428) + t(423) + t(407)
      , o = t(483) + "rTr" + t(446) + t(477) + "Id";
    C[t(489) + t(463) + t(469) + "cker"] = {
        ........................
        getTrackingUserIdParam: function() {
            return o
        },
        getUserId: function() {
            return I
        },
        ......................
    }
}(jQuery, window)
},
```

I've skipped a lot of code in the above snippet so it's more clear.

You can see that there are substitutions here, using the `t` array as a base, it will offset the strings using the `A` function and there is an init function that updated the initial `t` array so that it decodes to the right strings

You can paste this snippet into a nodejs script, modify it a little and then you can use something like:

```js
var t = ["PCl", "tUp", "set", "270981fHMpFv", "13687NsSiEo", "rId", "cri", "onR", "DEV", "oTr", "Int", "Tra", "_PR", "val", "1ceOiGP", "sts", "oad", "Fin", "_UA", "ing", "IdP", "TA_", "Scr", "erI", "hTo", "use", "erv", "tim", "tus", "205913gYUZtZ", "ara", "Use", "sta", "STA", "LBD", "pat", "253565HlVREe", "rva", "Ref", "now", "ien", "ref", "89874aJWuvR", "scr", "HTT", "arI", "equ", "efo", "Eve", "ngU", "1eAGUfS", "Url", "bef", "onl", "res", "p:/", "add", "nte", "rlT", "IdS", "Loa", "157231BKOPfc", "1YJedti", "hIn", "ate", "ser", "TDA", "bin", "upd", "xEr", "tou", "dHo", "ps:", "din", "931", "isU", "aja", "tup", "ste", "ntL", "Pat", "_DE", "ays", "onO", "edA", "Sen", "261593SNtpWc", "ore", "gth", "las", "730", "ame", "ter", "ime", "UAT", "id8", "ues", "est", "rtT", "xSe", "ist", "ptL", "ATA", "len", "ipt", "get", "pga", "Tru", "rep", "ish", "url", "alw", "dat", "ack", "lac", "onB", "uld", "cki", "ken", "ind", "onS", "sho", "htt", "ror", "API"];

var A = function(g, e) {
    return t[g -= 398]
};
console.log(t);
(function(g, e) {
    for (var t = A; ; )
        try {
            if (189298 === parseInt(t(494)) + -parseInt(t(508)) * parseInt(t(461)) + -parseInt(t(519)) + parseInt(t(419)) + -parseInt(t(520)) * -parseInt(t(487)) + parseInt(t(472)) * -parseInt(t(462)) + -parseInt(t(500)))
                break;
            g.push(g.shift())
        } catch (e) {
            g.push(g.shift())
        }
}
)(t)
console.log(t);
console.log(`e[${A(439) + A(403) + "r"}] = e[${"pga" + A(403) + "r"}] || {};`);

// prints e[pgatour] = e[pgatour] || {};
```

Here `e` is `window` so you "just" have to substitute all the `A(XXX)` in order to understand better what is going on.

You would spot this:

```js
onBeforeSendRequest: function(g, e) {
    var A = t;
    if (this[A(408) + A(516) + "oTr" + A(446)](e.url) && window[A(439) + A(403) + "r"][A(460) + A(469) + A(450) + A(507) + A(398) + "Id"]) {
        var I = this["getUse" + A(463)]()
            , o = window[A(439) + A(403) + "r"]["set" + A(469) + A(450) + A(507) + A(398) + "Id"](I)
            , n = this[A(438) + A(469) + A(450) + A(507) + "ser" + A(478) + A(488) + "m"]();
        e.url = C[A(460) + A(509) + "Par" + A(424) + A(425)](e[A(443)], n, o)
    }
},
```

which when decoded gives something like:

```js
onBeforeSendRequest: function(g, e) {
    if (this["isUrlToTrack"](e.url) && window["pgatour"]["setTrackingUserId"]) {
        var I = this["getUserId"]()
            , o = window["pgatour"]["setTrackingUserId"](I)
            , n = this["getTrackingUserIdParam"]();
        e.url = C["setUrlParameter"](e["url"], n, o)
    }
},
```

The function we are looking for is `window["pgatour"]["setTrackingUserId"]`. But we could have known this since mission n°1. Remember in the first JS file:

```
var t = u.setTrackingUserId
```

and `u` being `window.pgatour`

But here, we have `I` the input parameter that is hard coded :

```js
var I = A(428) + A(423) + A(407);
```

which is equivalent to `var I = "id8730931"`

Now let's look at `window["pgatour"]["setTrackingUserId"]` function

#### Mission n°3 - Crypto/reverse

Open chrome developer console on the website, paste `window["pgatour"]["setTrackingUserId"]` you will get something like this:

```js
function(_$_$){var $$ = _$__(_$_$); var _$_, ___, __;.................
```

Yes :( again more obfuscated code to deal with

By looking at the application script, you may find that it's located in [this file](https://microservice.pgatour.com/js?_=1618868625306). This is the JS file url:

```
https://microservice.pgatour.com/js?_=1618868625306
```

There is an url parameter specifying an epoch time and the code changes depending on this parameter

Looking at the code itself, we get something like this after substituing the input parameters which are `String.fromCharCode` and `Math.abs`

```js
((function($__$, _, $_$) { 
    var $$_ = 4294967295; <===================== doesn't change when the epoch time is updated
    function _$__($) {
        var $$__ = 42;
        for (var _ = 0; _ < $.length; _++) {
            $$__ = ($$__ * 31 + $.charCodeAt(_)) & $$_;
        }
        return Math.abs($$__);
    }
    ......
    _$_ = (__ * __ - $$) & $$_ ^ -30086, <===================== doesn't change when the epoch time is updated
    ___ += _(_$_),
    __ = _$_,
    _$_ = (__ * __ - $$) & $$_ ^ -33221,
    ___ += _(_$_),
    .....
    $__$[__$_] = (function(_$_$ = "id8730931") { <===================== this is window["pgatour"]["setTrackingUserId"] function / input is id8730931
        var $$ = _$__(_$_$);
        var _$_, ___, __;
        var __ = (__ = 101,
        ___ = String.fromCharCode(__),
        _$_ = (__ * __ - $$) & $$_ ^ -1798328965, <===================== this change when epoch time is updated
        ___ += String.fromCharCode(_$_),
        __ = _$_,
        _$_ = (__ * __ - $$) & $$_ ^ -1798324966,
        ___ += String.fromCharCode(_$_),
        __ = _$_,
        ....
        __ = _$_,
        ___);
        return __
    }
    );
}
)((window.pgatour || (window.pgatour = {})), String.fromCharCode, Math.abs));
```

We can make a [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) script to reproduce this algorithm in a simpler way by extracting the step value (in the xor stage):

```js
const axios = require("axios");

const init = 4294967295;
var value = 101;
var encodedId = 1798339286;
var result = String.fromCharCode(value);

(async function () {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://microservice.pgatour.com/js?_=1618868625506"
  );
  data = response.data.match(/-17\d+/g).map((it) => parseInt(it));

  for (t of data) {
    var step = ((value * value - encodedId) & init) ^ t;
    result += String.fromCharCode(step);
    value = step;
  }
  console.log(result);
})();
```

output:

```
exp=1618882930~acl=*~hmac=0274aecb617168167713a757e301c33e9708da3ab643663f97a4775040bf3bdd
```

If you change the epoch time, it will give a different result

repl.it: https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/PegatourEncrypt

Then you just need to convert this [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) script in [r](/questions/tagged/r) and make your http call with the url parameters

Note that `encodedId` comes from the input id `id8730931` converted using this function (those values don't seem to change with the epoch time):

```js
var $$_ = 4294967295;
function _$__($) {
    var $$__ = 42;
    for (var _ = 0; _ < $.length; _++) {
        $$__ = ($$__ * 31 + $.charCodeAt(_)) & $$_;
    }
    return Math.abs($$__);
}
```

My guess is that the server is checking that the hmac is correctly referring to the initial id string `id8730931` so it's safe to harcode (since it's also harcoded in the server)

Comment: Going to need a day to review this, but for now i've accepted + bountied because it seems unlikely that anyone else will help this much. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Thanks for this. I got part way through solving then lost the golden thread. Really appreciate the detail +