# Using rvest to scrape from an html site, but returns results "category (empty)"

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

Below is a sample of the html code from the site that I'm trying to scrape:

[image]

And here's the code that I'm using specifically trying to get the text after "shot-text" that says "Shot 1 307 yds to left fairway, 231 yds to hole":

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

golf <- read_html("https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html")

shots <- golf %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes("div") %>%
  xml2::xml_find_all("//div[contains(@class, 'shot-text')]") %>% 
  rvest::html_text()
```

But when I run this it just returns "character (empty)" - what could I be doing wrong? I'm very inexperienced with this.

Comment: Are you sure the data isn't loaded via javascript after the page loads? Note that what you see in the "elements" tab of the developer tools is the current state, but what you see in "sources" is what the server sent and what rvest can see. The rvest package can't execute javascript. You'll either need to reverse engineer the site to figure out where the data is coming from or use something like RSelenium to run the javascript for you.

Comment: @MrFlick no, I'm not sure of that. How could I check that?

Comment: Do we have to expand something to see this text?

Comment: @QHarr what text are you referring to?

Comment: `Shot 1 307 yds to left fairway, 231 yds to hole`. I don't see it.

Comment: @QHarr that’s the only text there is in that row, but there should be multiple items with the shot-text tag

Comment: Does one have to be logged in?

Comment: @QHarr nope, this is just from the PGA website

Comment: Yes, this site uses JavaScript to create the page.  See this question as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66056386/scraping-leaderboard-table-on-golf-website-in-r