# Confusion Regarding HTML Code For Web Scraping With R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am struggling using the `rvest` package in R, most likely due to my lack of knowledge about CSS or HTML. Here is an example (my guess is the ".quote-header-info" is what is wrong, also tried the ".Trsdu ..." but no luck either):

```
library(rvest)
url="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY"

website=read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".quote-header-info") %>%
  html_text() %>% toString()

website
```

The below is the webpage I am trying to scrape. Specifically looking to grab the value "416.74". I took a peek at the documentation here (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf) but think the issue is I don't understand the breakdown of the webpage I am looking at.

[image]

Comment: This is a javascript web page, you'll need RSelenium or equivalent, see [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66217591/13513328)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part is determining the correct set of attributes to only select this one html node.

In this case the **span** tag with a class of *Trsdu(0.3s)* and *Fz(36px)*

```
library(rvest)
url="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY"

#read page once
page <- read_html(url)

#now extract information from the page
price <- page %>%  html_nodes("span.Trsdu\\(0\\.3s\\).Fz\\(36px\\)") %>%
   html_text()

price
```

Note: "(", ")", and "." are all special characters thus the need to double escape "\\" them.

Comment: Beautiful, it was the special characters that I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Those classes are dynamic and change much more frequently than other parts of the html. They should be avoided. You have at least two more robust options.

1. Extract the javascript option housing that data (plus a lot more) in a script tag then parse with jsonlite
2. Use positional matching against other, more stable, html elements

I show both below. The advantage of the first is that you can extract lots of other page data from the json object generated.

---

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)

page <- read_html('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY')

data <- page %>% 
  toString() %>% 
  stringr::str_match('root\\.App\\.main = (.*?[\\s\\S]+)(?=;[\\s\\S]+\\(th)') %>% .[2]

json <- jsonlite::parse_json(data)
print(json$context$dispatcher$stores$StreamDataStore$quoteData$SPY$regularMarketPrice$raw)
print(page %>% html_node('#quote-header-info div:nth-of-type(2) ~ div div:nth-child(1) span') %>% html_text() %>% as.numeric())
```

Comment: How can I generalize this to other websites? For example, how would I pull the data from this url: https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/rates-bonds/bloomberg-barclays-indices

Comment: you generalize through applying the principles I mention above. If elements of the page are known, or suspected, to be dynamic (and by that, I specifically mean frequently changing their attribute value(s) as Yahoo Finance does with those class attributes), look for something more stable. Another strategy is to look for an API source. That latter one is almost certainly the best option if you can find a publicly available, maintained, and ideally free, one. There is no one size fits all in web-scraping. Depending on factors such as: the frameworks, shared designer, shared domain,

Comment: you may be able to group some sites into similar strategies | re-use same code and swop out urls. That is generally the exception. The next thing is, you can use OOP principles to pull out the logic, which generally doesn't vary across different requests, into re-usable functions e.g. creating a soup object that takes url as parameter.